# Hangfire configure delayed task expiration time if overdue

Tags: hangfire, delayed-execution

Is it possible to set expiration time from configuration for delayed tasks?
If they are overdue,dispose them after if configured amount of time has already passed?

Comment: You want to delay a task but make it expire? So it may not run?

Comment: No lets say it is planned to run at 2:00 am and I dont want it to run after lets say 2:05 if it didnt have chance to run.So that 5 minute is the amount I wanna be able to configure.After this time task execution has no meaning in my case.

Comment: I see. But in your example, if it is planned to run at 2:00, then it will. Or am I missing something? Are you afraid there might be too many items in the queue?

Comment: for some reason at that time schedule server may not be working or throttled for some time or maybe there has been a network issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of this functionality existing in Hangfire.
However you can code it by creating a [`JobFilterAttribute`](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/extensibility/using-job-filters.html), something like this:

```
public class MyJobFilterAttribute : JobFilterAttribute, IElectStateFilter
{
    private DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }
    private int ExpirationInMinutes { get; set; }

    public MyJobFilterAttribute(int expirationInMinutes)
    {
        this.ExpirationInMinutes = expirationInMinutes;
        this.CreationTime = DateTime.Now;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Election of a new state: if the new state is "enqueued" then set the queue to use
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    public void OnStateElection(ElectStateContext context)
    {
        var enqueuedState = context.CandidateState as EnqueuedState;
        if ((DateTime.Now - CreationTime) > new TimeSpan(0, ExpirationInMinutes, 0))
        {
            Hangfire.BackgroundJob.Delete(context.BackgroundJob.Id);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you will add the attribute to the target method of your job:

```
[MyJobFilter(5)]
public void MyJobWithExpiration() {}


public void MyCallingMethod() {
    BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => MyJobWithExpiration());
}
```

Note: code not tested, this is the general idea

Comment: I have implemented the similar way to your suggestion 
 according to  https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/issues/1170